# Threading in .net Core Worker Services

Tags: multithreading, .net-core, backgroundworker

What is the intended usage of Worker Services in .net Core 3 with respect to threading. Is it expected that the need for multiple threads be handled as background threads within Workers or is there a pattern for adding multiple Workers ([similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58229410/multiple-workers-in-net-core-worker-services)) with in CreateHOstBuilder() and respected by all of its extension methods?